# Import a large SP List over 40K records from tenant to another

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, import

I have 2 SP lists on an old tenant that holds more than 25-45k records and I want to migrate both lists to a new tenant with the same number of items.

I did my research and found that only 20k items in total are supported to be imported using spreadsheet, so if the number is greater than that it will throw an error during the import.

I have tried the below methods:

1. Import from spreadsheet method by following the below article.

[Import from Spreadsheet MS lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-list-based-on-a-spreadsheet-380cfeb5-6e14-438e-988a-c2b9bea574fa)

2. Import the list by using a list template but unfortunately, I cannot include the content because the list is large over 23k records and another one over 40k.

So I am trying to find a workaround to import those two large lists to the new tenant SP site.

Can someone recommend the method that should be used with an example or provide a third-party tool that can achieve the above?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!